# What is the correct http verb for Django REST partial_update

Tags: python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

Im trying to perform partial update in DRF using angular $http.

In my DRF model viewset i override the `partial_update` function (server side).

```
class AnimalTreatmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyObject.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyObjectSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        # It works with $http.post()
        pass

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        # It works with $http.put()
        pass

    def list(self, request):
        # It works with $http.get()
        pass

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        # This one wont work with $http.patch()
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.serializer_class(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In the client side angular handle the user request.

```
$http.patch('/api/my_viewset_url/1', data);
```

But i got this response **Method Not Allowed (PATCH): /api/my_viewset_url/1**

> When using `$http.get()` request with DRF model viewset `list(self, request)` it works well for getting a list same goes for `$http.post()` with `def create(self, request)` for creating object and `$http.put()` with `def update(self, request)` for updating object.

**What's wrong? or what is the correct http verb for partial_update in DRF model viewset**

Comment: are you using a modelviewset? which mixins? can you share the rest of the viewset? thanks!!

Comment: im using modelviewset, thanks for the response!

Comment: @bobleujr i updated my question

Comment: it looks weird.. have you tried to explicitly add the urls as_view, just in case your router is doing something weird.. like url(r'^api/update-partial/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', YourView.as_view(), name='item_partial_update'),

Comment: silly question, but: have you tried that same call with trailing slash?

Comment: @bobleujr yeah im sure it is correct

Comment: @DiegoPonciano YEAH! i forgot the '/' at the end! tsk! haha thanks a lot

Comment: good call haha!

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab I'll add it as an answer :D

Comment: @DiegoPonciano WHAT? you dont have to comment your motive just post an answer already XD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the URL is missing a trailing slash.

Related [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter):

> By default the URLs created by SimpleRouter/DefaultRouter are appended with a
>   trailing slash. This behavior can be modified by setting the trailing_slash argument to False when instantiating the router. For example:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
```